# $H\leq G$ implies $H^{'}\leq G^{'}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group. The **commutator** of $a, b\in G$ is defined as $[a, b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. The **commutator subgroup** of $G$ is defined as $$G^{'}=\langle [a, b]: a, b\in G\rangle,$$ that is, $G^{'}$ is the subgroup generated by the commutators of $G$.

Is it true that if $H\leq G$ then $H^{'}\leq G^{'}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you see the commutators of $H$ are also commutators of $G$?

can you see that in general if $X\subseteq Y$ then $\langle X \rangle \leq  \langle Y \rangle$

Hint for the second part: What is the form of the elements of $\langle X \rangle$?

Comment: woops, thank you Timbuc. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, thanks =) I've just seen your second statement is an exercise in the book "Abstract Algebra" by D. Foote and R. Foote =)

Comment: That book is awesome, I'm working through it also!

Comment: That's nice =).